# Using JQuery UI's sortable('serialize') after loading data in via .load();

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a page (page1.php) where I am using a select box to load in another page (page2.php) into a DIV. Inside page2.php there is a UL that loads data from a database (via PHP) into LIs and the are sortable.

My problem is, when I load page2.php by itself, it serializes fine. However, when page2.php is loaded via .load() into page1.php, it doesn't serialize at all and I get undefined.

Here is the important code, again this works fine by itself, but not when this page is loaded in via the .load() function

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<style> 
    #thelist { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width:700px; }
    #thelist li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 200px; height: 150px; }
    </style> 
<ul id="thelist">
<li style="margin-bottom:5px;" name='listItem_1' id='listItem_1'>
    test1
</li>
<li style="margin-bottom:5px;" name='listItem_2' id='listItem_2'>
    test2
</li>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $("#thelist").sortable({ 
            update : function () { 
              var order = $('#thelist').sortable('serialize'); 
              alert(order); // This alerts "undefined" when page2.php is loaded into page1.php via .load();
              $("#info").load("reorder_slides.php?"+order); 
        }});
    });
</script>
```

This is the new code I am running, still to no avail.

```
<script>
    $('#edit_service_date').change(function() {
        // $(this).val()
        $('#editService').slideUp("slow",function(){
            $('#thelist').load('page2.php', {id: $('#edit_service_date').val()}, function(){
                $("#thelist").sortable({ 
                    update : function () { 
                      var order = $('#thelist').sortable('serialize'); 
                      alert(order); // This alerts "undefined" when page2.php is loaded into page1.php via .load();
                      $("#info").load("reorder_slides.php?"+order); 
                }});
                if($('#edit_service_date').val()!="none"){
                    $('#editService').slideDown("slow");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're loading the entirety of the above into a div in another page that also has its own jQuery and ready() handler?

Comment: you can't use $(function(){}); inside JS code that is retrieved via Ajax, but only on "regular" page loading. Instead you need to define a new JS initialization function that you call from the onComplete method of your Ajax callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If everything you posted above is being brought into another page via `.load()`, then I see (at least) two problems:

1. You're loading jQuery and jQuery UI twice: once in the outer page, and once in the inner page loaded via ajax. There's no need.
2. You're expecting `$(function(){})` to fire after being loaded into the "inner" page within the `div`. `$(function(){})` is a synonym for `$(document).ready( function(){} )`, and in fact the `ready` event has already fired (when the outer page DOM became ready). It won't do anything here.

You should try triggering the `.sortable()` stuff inside the callback of the `.load()` you're using to bring the inner document into the `div`:

```
/* on page1.php */
$('#yourdiv').load( 'page2.php', function(){
    $('#thelist').sortable( /* arguments */ );
});
```

Comment: Ken, thanks for your input.

I tried what you suggested, but to no avail. Also, I'd like to point out that I don't want to serialize when the page loads, but rather when the sortable function is updated. I have updated my first post with the new code I am running.

Comment: Nick, in your revised code it looks like you have an element with the id `thelist` (the container -- is this supposed to be a `div`?), to which you apply `.load()`...and then in the callback you apply `.sortable()` to that same id. So you're loading into an id, and in the loaded content you have a list with that same id -- and then you're trying to make that ambiguous id sortable?

Comment: Ken, I toyed around with loading LIs into the UL (#thelist) to see if keeping the UL on the main page would make it serialize. This method didn't work, but as of right now I'm loading the whole UL into a div, #editService

Comment: Ken, I went back and reread your first post. After removing the calls to jquery and jquery-ui in the second page, it works fine... very odd but I'm a little upset I wasted a couple hours on that.

I appreciate your willingness to help, and if I could vote your anwer up I would do so!

Comment: Nick, glad to hear you got it sorted out.